# Custom label is now missing

Tags: iphone

The 'Custom Label' in Contacts is now gone missing on my iPhone 5c, how do I restore this label to my contacts?

Answer (score -1):

I think the *Custom Label* field is only visible for contacts on GMail, as opposed to on iCloud. Go to **Settings → Mail Contacts, Calendars → Contacts / Default Account** and set it to your gmail account. For the contacts you create now, they'll be saved on GMail and the *Custom Label* field will be available.

Comment: Kind stranger, may I have an explanation for the down vote please?